# PHP - Displaying checkbox based on certain conditions

Tags: php, object

I have a collection of Objects which take the following form

```
#attributes: array:8 [▼
    "name" => "Something1"
    "value" => "Some Data"
]

#attributes: array:8 [▼
    "name" => "Something1Test"
    "value" => "Some Data"
]

#attributes: array:8 [▼
    "name" => "NOC M2"
    "value" => "Some Data"
]

#attributes: array:8 [▼
    "name" => "Couldbeanything M3"
    "value" => "Some Data"
]

#attributes: array:8 [▼
    "name" => "Couldbeanything M3Test"
    "value" => "Some Data"
]
```

If a name attribute ends with Test, the preceding Object is related to it.  So for instance Something1Test is related to Something1.  The first part will always be the same "Something1", the cloned version just has Test added to the end.

I am looping my Objects and displaying their content.  What I am trying to do is display a checkbox for all Objects that do not have a related Test Object.  At the moment I have something like this

```
<?php if(strpos($data->name, 'Test') === false) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        //Display a checkbox
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Now this somewhat works in a sense that it displays a checkbox for all Objects that dont have a name attribute which contains Test.  So for the above data, it is displaying a checkbox for

```
Something1
NOC M2
Couldbeanything M3
```

The problem I am having is that Something1 and Couldbeanything have a related Test Object, so these two should not have a checkbox.  With the above data, the only thing that should have a checkbox is NOC M2, because there is no NOC M2Test.

Is there any way to achieve what I am after?  The first part of the name could be anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first gather the names:

```
$names = array_column($objects, 'name');
```

The above assumes a nested array structure; you may need to do something like this instead:

```
$names = array();
foreach ($objects as $data) {
    $names[] = $data->name;
}
```

Then I would perform the following check:

```
// Must not end in Test and must not have a corresponding Test object
if (substr($data->name, -4) != 'Test' && !in_array($data->name . 'Test', $names)) {
    // do my output here
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Theoretically, $objects is an Object, and not an array.  Therefore, I cant really use array_column.  Is there another way to approach this?

Comment: I've just added an edit for that; assuming `$objects` is iterable, you can use `foreach`.